# Find latest file in a directory whose name starts with <> using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

So I have a directory where logs files are getting created and I want to read latest log files. This directory will have log files, error files and some other files which will be getting created every time. My log file will have name starting with say test-install-<>.log

How do I find which is the latest log file using batch script.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "lastLog="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d "x:\logsFolder\test-install-*.log" 2^>nul') do (
        if not defined lastLog set "lastLog=%%a"
    )

    echo %lastLog%
```

Or, for a long list of files, to avoid iterations

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "lastLog="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d "x:\logsFolder\test-install-*.log" 2^>nul') do (
        set "lastLog=%%a" 
        goto :done
    )
:done
    echo %lastLog%
```

Or, if you have a really big list of files

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "lastLog="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /b /o-d "x:\logsFolder\test-install-*.log" 2^>nul
        ^| cmd /q /v /c"set /p .=&if defined . (echo(!.!)"
    ') do set "lastLog=%%a" 
    echo %lastLog%
```

Comment: Great.. Just what I wanted. Thanks @MC ND